# How much data we can store inside atlas 500mb sandbox?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I working on a project. Where I was implemented MongoDB. I want to know how many records we can store inside the 500MB atlas sandbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _...how many records we can store inside 500mb ..._ Well 500mb devided by your record size

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/request-limit-in-the-free-tier/9804/2